# Posting base64 image to php server in android

Tags: php, android, image, base64

I am working on a module in which user can upload the image to the server.  To achieve this, I have to change selected image into Base64. After conversion, I have to use Json POST method to upload image, but every time application crashes and Logcat give this error

```
Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
```

and another line of error is

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

this is my code that I am trying, Please have a look and let me what mistake I am doing here.

```
    buttonLoadPicture.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                    startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

        ss = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
        Log.d("value", ss.toString());


        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
        ss.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b,Base64.DEFAULT);

        encodedImage = imageEncoded.toString();

        Log.e("LOOK", imageEncoded); // **working proper**
        Log.e("encodedImage", encodedImage);// **working proper**

       new PostImage().execute();

    }
}

class PostImage extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String encodedString = encodedImage.toString();

        Log.d("stringgggg", encodedString);//**working proper**

     List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uploaded_file", encodedString));
        String uri = "http://192.168.2.166/uploadimage/upload.php";         
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(uri,"POST",params);

        Log.d("valueeeeee", json.toString());// **Crashhhh!!!!!**
        return json.toString();
    }
}
```

}

this is my php code

```
<?php

    $json["success"] = 1; $json["message"] = "YOU ARE HERE... UPLOAD.PHP";

    $json['image']=$_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
    $json['tmp_name']=$_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'];
    echo json_encode($json);

    die();
    //print_r($_FILES); die();
    $file_path = "uploads/";

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
        //echo "success";
         $json["success"] = 1; $json["message"] = "Successfully post save"; 
    } else{
       // echo "fail";
         $json["success"] = 0; $json["message"] = "Fail post save"; 
    }

    // print_r($json);
    // var_dump(json_encode($json));
    echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Comment: You are able to create BASE64 right?

Comment: where are your makeHttpRequest ?

Answer (score 0):

Please assign encoded value to used params

```
     encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(b,Base64.DEFAULT);
      Log.e("LOOK", encodedString);

      new PostImage().execute(encodedString);
```

Comment: Hello Shoeb, I amazed how I can do this mistake. But brother I am getting the same error after the correction.  and one more thing, when I am converting the image into base64 and printing the in Log.e("LOOK", encodedString); It prints so many values like this..

Comment: 07-06 02:36:22.419: E/LOOK(1339): /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
07-06 02:36:22.419: E/LOOK(1339): AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
07-06 02:36:22.419: E/LOOK(1339): AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/wAARCAHgAoADASIA
07-06 02:36:22.419: E/LOOK(1339): AhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQA
07-06 02:36:22.419: E/LOOK(1339): AAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3
07-06 02:36:22.419: E/LOOK(1339): ODk6Q0RFR

Answer (score 0):

Add **httpmime-4.3.6.jar** and httpcore-4.3.3.jar into your libs folder and add into build.gradle and sync it than after do this step;

This variable You have to define;

```
 private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
 public static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "Android File Upload";
Uri mImageCaptureUri;
private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
 File sourceFile;
ProgressDialog pDialog;
ContentBody pic;
Bitmap bitmap;
```

than open gallary code.put into your Onclick.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

this is OnActivityResult

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
            && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        decodeFile(picturePath);
        new ImageUploadTask().execute();
    }else {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Canceled",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

after this

```
  public void decodeFile(String filePath) {
    // Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o);

    // The new size we want to scale to
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 1024;

    // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
    int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
    int scale = 1;
    while (true) {
        if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE)
            break;
        width_tmp /= 2;
        height_tmp /= 2;
        scale *= 2;
    }

    // Decode with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);
    sourceFile = new File(filePath);
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, bos);
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
    pic = new ByteArrayBody(bos.toByteArray(),"filename");
    loadimage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}



/**
 * The class connects with server and uploads the photo
 *
 *
 */
class ImageUploadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {


    private String webAddressToPost;

    // private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Tab1.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
       dialog.setMessage("Uploading...");
       dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {

            // HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("YOUR URL");

            MultipartEntity entity1 = new MultipartEntity(
                    HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
            byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
          //  String file = com.onepgr.samcom.apicalldemo2.Base64.encodeBytes(data);
            entity1.addPart("Parameter", pic);

            // entity.addPart("someOtherStringToSend", new StringBody("your string here"));

            httpPost.setEntity(entity1);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            String sResponse = reader.readLine();
            Log.d("------>>>>",sResponse);
            return sResponse;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // something went wrong. connection with the server error
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Profile picture change",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

Don't forget to add httpmime-4.3.6.jar and httpcore-4.3.3.jar file into your project.

Comment: thanx for your answer bro but what is 'MultipartEntity' and 'HttpMultipartMode'

Comment: please Compile This Two library i listed in answer.U will understand All things.and its Work for me perfectly @Devraj

Comment: I have downloaded and added these files in my lib folder. but still there are some variables that undefined in my code, can u please share your complete code.

Comment: you Can see my Updated answer @Devraj

Comment: Tell me Which Type your Upload image i mean Through Camera capture or gallary? @Devraj

Comment: No NO, not from camera, from gallery only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82466/discussion-between-rushabh042-and-devraj).