# android-send username and get details as json object from http server

Tags: android, json, http

In my login page, I have to send the username to http server and fetch user details like name,number,etc as json object. I am new to network connection and json.  I know there are plenty of examples out there but could someone point me to an actual tutorial? I'm looking for a step by step process with code and explanation of why you do each step, or of what that step does. It doesn't need to be a complex, simple will suffice.

Comment: see my answer will help you for the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31238764/posting-base64-image-to-php-server-in-android/31238916?noredirect=1#comment50477664_31238916

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go Step wise, first you need to create a server code (write API)
then you have to consume it in your android code.

follow this tutorial you will get a clear idea

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/